# I would like to loop through my model list in razor to fill jquery columns

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, datatable

I want to generate a table from a list however I do not know how to do it. 
Here is a picture of the error I am getting.

[image: Error]

Here is my html code

```
<table id="extracionTable" class="display nowrap" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model.contactos)
            {
                <th>@item.nombre_contacto</th>
            }
    </thead>
</table>
```

And here is the jQuery code

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#extracionTable').DataTable({
            rowReorder: {
                selector: 'td:nth-child(2)'
            },
            responsive: true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/gestionDeEmpleados/loadEmployeTable",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                @foreach (var item in Model.contactos) { 
                { "data": @item, "autoWidth": true },/* index = 0 */
                }
            ]
        });
    });
    $("#open-new").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
</script>
```

How can I fix this.

Comment: When you run your code, are you actually getting an error? Many times, when you mix different languages, the IDE shows errors by mistake but the code is actually good. I'm not familiar with Razor but if the code starting with @ are being processed by the backend, the code should be good. PS: Bonjour du Québec!

Comment: Yes I have tried it I get an erreur that says expected ;  Thank you chère inconnue du québec.

Comment: If you look at the rendered source code, what's the output for the columns object ?

Comment: Also, just to be sure that the error is coming from that line of code, hardcode the object without your ASP code. Something like: "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" }
        ]

Comment: Without asp.net code it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly the problem is that your code is confusing Razor.  For example you have curly braces that are meant to be for a javascript object but Razor thinks they are part of your C# code.

I think your best way forward would be to convert your data to JSON and send it to the view that way.  Then get your jQuery to access this JSON and work with it.  The advantage of this approach is that your javascript no longer has to live on the view which is not really where it belongs.  If you'd like I can expand on this further?

If you really want to do it the way you have shown then one way it could be done is to change your second foreach to this.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.contactos) 
            {
                <text>
                    { "data": "@(item.nombre_contacto)", "autoWidth": true },
              </text>
           }
```

I have used the `<text>` elements here to help Razor decipher what is C# code and what is a string it should ignore.

**Edit** I've just run this with some test data and the code wouldn't work until I changed the ajax property.  Try it like this

```
"ajax": {
            "url": "/gestionDeEmpleados/loadEmployeTable",
            "type": "GET",
            "datatype": "json",
            "dataSrc":""
        }
```

Note I have added the dataSrc property.  Reading the datatable docs it says the dataSrc option is used to tell DataTables where the data array is in the JSON structure so empty string might not work for you.  See [their ajax docs](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax) for more.

Comment: Thank you, however it does not work for me I can see when I inspect the element that it has generated the following code <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#extracionTable').DataTable({
                        "ajax": {
                "url": "/extraccion/loadExtraccionTable",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json",
            }, rowReorder: { selector: 'td:nth-child(2)'},responsive: true,"columns": [{{ "data": tata, "autoWidth": true },...</script> however it does nothing

Comment: I think it was missing quotes.  Try it now with the quotes

Comment: Thank you, I have added the quotes but it still does not work I get the same result but with quotes around the data values.

Comment: Have you used the developer tools to look at the console, is it displaying any errors?

Comment: Yes but I dont see any erreurs

Comment: I figured it out I had a { to much Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

it's like Dave said, you have braces for the code `foreach` in razor followed by braces for the javascript. You need to tell razor how to interpret it. 
A similar way to do that more crealy would be this:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.contactos) { 
            <text>
                { "data": @(item.nombre_contacto), "autoWidth": true },/* index = 0 */
            </text>
 }
```

That way i think it's more readable, the `@()` will print out the value of what's inside